# Slow Index scan on PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, performance

I have a table named `foo_partition_20210501`, which has a size of ~10GB and contains ~100M rows. As you may guess it is a partition of a partitioned table, but I don't think has something to do with the problem I'm encountering, as I'm only working on one partition at a time.

The table has multiple columns, but three are of interest:

- item_id: integer
- item_date: date
- code: custom type `enum_code`

Many of the records of the table have a code = 'A', and I often filter on the tuple (item_id, item_date). So I've created the following partial index:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_foo_partition_20210501_partial_index 
ON public.foo_partition_20210501 
USING btree (item_date, item_id) 
WHERE (code <> 'A'::enum_code)
```

The partial index is ~50MB large.

When I query the table such as

```
SELECT * 
FROM foo_partition_20210501 
WHERE item_date='20210521' 
AND item_id=137415 
AND code IN ('B', 'C')
```

The resulting plan (explain analyze+buffers) contains this:

```
->  Index Scan using ix_foo_partition_20210501_partial_index on foo_partition_20210501  (cost=0.43..18.00 rows=8 width=62) (actual time=460.775..20533.036 rows=63 loops=1)
                                                                                            
Index Cond: ((item_date = '2021-05-21'::date) AND (item_id = 137415))
"Filter: (code = ANY ('{B,C}'::enum_code[]))"
Rows Removed by Filter: 1841
Buffers: shared hit=2 read=1124 dirtied=76
I/O Timings: read=20418.129
```

So the query plan is correct and does use my partial index, but is very slow (20s). It does read the disk instead of the cache, but I still don't understand why it would be so slow. The index is fairly small (only 50MB), and the number of overall rows fetched is less than 2000 with only 63 being kept.

Do you have any insight on why this is slow ? is it normal disk read performance for PostgreSQL ?

Details of the platform:

- PostgreSQL 12.5 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
- SAN Disk

Running the same query multiple times:

When hitting the cache, it's very fast.

```
Index Scan using ix_foo_partition_20210501_partial_index on foo_partition_20210501  (cost=0.43..18.00 rows=8 width=62) (actual time=0.080..4.672 rows=63 loops=1)
Index Cond: ((foo_date = '2021-05-21'::date) AND (foo_id = 137415))
"Filter: (code = ANY ('{B,C}'::enum_code[]))"
Rows Removed by Filter: 1843
Buffers: shared hit=1128
```

Some times hitting the disk is still slow but only 8s here:

```
Index Scan using ix_foo_partition_20210501_partial_index on foo_partition_20210501  (cost=0.43..18.00 rows=8 width=62) (actual time=30.511..8135.828 rows=63 loops=1)
Index Cond: ((foo_date = '2021-05-21'::date) AND (foo_id = 137415))
"Filter: (code = ANY ('{B,C}'::enum_code[]))"
Rows Removed by Filter: 1843
Buffers: shared hit=4 read=1124
I/O Timings: read=8084.544
```

Answer (score 3):

Reading 1124 blocks to get 1904 rows is unfortunate, but normal.

What is not normal is the I/O time: almost 20 ms for a single 8kB block. Either your I/O system is really overloaded, or the disk is amazingly slow.

Comment: Is there a postgres configuration parameter that can have an impact on disk read performance ?

Comment: Also do you have any experience with postgres running on the cloud (typically using SAN) ? what is the expected I/O performance ?

Comment: 20ms is slow but not unheared of for cloud remote storage. You might want to get more expensive disks (for example on Azure the Ultra Disks have better latency or the Premiere Storage with local cache. Make sure to use the smaller P disks like P30 and ideally use striping on them if you need more storage capacity.

Comment: There is nothing that PostgreSQL can do to speed up the disk.

Answer (score 2):

> is it normal disk read performance for PostgreSQL ?

PostgreSQL doesn't read your disk.  It tells the kernel to read the disk, then waits for it to respond.  You need to have a discussion with whoever is in charge of your SAN and networking about what should be considered normal for it.

> Some times hitting the disk is still slow but only 8s here:

PostgreSQL can only distinguish hitting shared_buffers vs asking the kernel to read the data in.  The kernel might be able to fulfill the request from its own filesystem cache, rather than actually hitting the disk.  PostgreSQL has no way of knowing that and reports either of those cases as a "read" rather than a "hit".  So not all "reads" are expected to take the same amount of time.

Assuming that slow IO is just something you have to live with, this query could be greatly improved by:

```
CREATE INDEX ON public.foo_partition_20210501 (item_date, item_id, code) 
    WHERE (code <> 'A'::enum_code);
```

That way it can remove things that are none of A or B or C by using the index rather than hitting the table.

Comment: Do you have a typical order of magnitude of what should be the performance with SAN ? (like for a standard cloud provider). Dully noted for the index, i will change it after the investigation is over ;)

Comment: "Typical" should be to meet their promises.  For example on AWS the smallest gp2 storage instances  (33GB or below) should offer sustained throughput of 100 IOPS, which is twice the performance that are seeing here (but maybe you have more than one task going on at once and they have to split up the throughput).  As the volume size gets larger the IOPS should go up, and you can switch to other classes that let you pay for more IOPS.